# Unknown encoding php file and can not be read

Tags: php

First thing first. I'm newbie in PHP programming. 
I've a project written in PHP but the file *.php are encoded>
Here is an example of the code:

[encoded php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhYRS.png)

[image]
I know this file is encoded (ANSI, UTF8, ISO 8859-6, ....)
How can I convert this to a readable file??
Thanks in advance

Comment: is not your editor able to identify the encoding? try them. 
What is your text editor?

Comment: I'm using notepad++ . and no it didn't identify the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see your file is probably encoded using [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard), compare your code with the screen shot from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyKvplwwej0 at 03:57.

There are tools available that might decode the file but the code will still be obfuscated. This means that all names of variables, functions, methods and classes are reduced to some glibberish which will not help you to understand the meaning of the code.

Most of the time this type of code will be pretty much useless as it may be very hard to understand and maintain. To get a feeling for the type of code you may get by decoding your file have a look at the before/after obfuscating example at http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/PHPObfuscationExample.html. Is this really what you want/need?

Another point to look at is the license under which your encoded php file is distributed. As Zend guard is a commercial tool it's mostly used to protect copyright and license of some piece of software. Most probably you will not be allowed to decode and modify that kind of code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several online site which does the Job.

https://www.unphp.net/

http://ddecode.com/phpdecoder/

give it a try.